# Unknown user in postfix (virtualmin)

Tags: postfix

I'm getting these mailer daemon errors when receiving email to support@domain2.com.

Both domain1.com and domain2.com are main level domains in virtualmin. I can't understand why domain1.com is mentioned here and what are these users "*", ":0" and "c".

```
<*@domain1.com> (expanded from <support@domain2.com>): unknown user: "*"

<":0"@domain1.com> (expanded from <support@domain2.com>): unknown user: ":0"

<c@domain1.com> (expanded from <support@domain2.com>): unknown user: "c"

Final-Recipient: rfc822; *@domain1.com
Original-Recipient: rfc822;support@domain2.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.1.1
Diagnostic-Code: X-Postfix; unknown user: "*"

Final-Recipient: rfc822; ":0"@domain1.com
Original-Recipient: rfc822;support@domain2.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.1.1
Diagnostic-Code: X-Postfix; unknown user: ":0"

Final-Recipient: rfc822; c@domain1.com
Original-Recipient: rfc822;support@domain2.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.1.1
Diagnostic-Code: X-Postfix; unknown user: "c"
```

Comment: This looks like a procmailrc entry gone wrong.

Comment: That's right, I found it. I searched the problem at postfix's configurations first. Thank you!